# Cascading generic interfaces

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface

I am building my own framework to wrap the interfaces exposed via  `Microsoft.Office.Interop`.

I wrap Office-wide functionalities into a first set of interfaces, which are then inherited by a second set of functionalities, which are application-dependent.

Here is a simplified version:

```
Region "Office Wrappers"

    Interface IApplication(Of T As IFile(Of IVariable))    
        Property Files As IList(Of T)    
    End Interface

    Interface IFile(Of T As IVariable)    
        Property Variables As IList(Of T)    
    End Interface

    Interface IVariable    
    End Interface    

#End Region    

#Region "Word Wrappers"

    Interface IWordApp 'ERROR BC32044
        Inherits IApplication(Of IWordDocument(Of IVariable, IWordParagraph))    
    End Interface

    Interface IWordDocument(Of TVar As IVariable, TPara As IWordParagraph)
        Inherits IFile(Of TVar)    
        Property Paragraphs As TPara    
    End Interface

    Interface IWordVariable
        Inherits IVariable    
    End Interface

    Interface IWordParagraph    
    End Interface

#End Region
```

The above sample returns an error (see `'ERROR BC32044` comment in the sample):

> Type argument 'IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable, IWordParagraph)' does not inherit from or implement the constraint type 'IFile(Of IVariable)'.

In order to fix this, I need to replace `IWordVariable` by `IVariable` in two instances:

```
Interface IWordApp
    Inherits IApplication(Of IWordDocument(Of IVariable, IWordParagraph)) '<- Replacement 1 of 2 here
End Interface

Interface IWordDocument(Of TVar As IVariable, TPara As IWordParagraph) '<- Replacement 2 of 2 here
    Inherits IFile(Of TVar)
    Property Paragraphs As TPara
End Interface
```

Since `IWordVariable` inherits from `IVariable`, I though `AnyGeneric(Of T as IVariable)` should accept `AnyGeneric(Of IWordVariable)`.

Why does the original code not compile, and how can I fix this?

---

#### Additional information & question

I use generics first because each application (Word, Excel, etc) relies on a set of base interfaces (as explained above), but also because I then "extend" each wrapper to expose some custom functionalities. For example:

```
Interface IExtendedWordDocument
    Inherits IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable, IExtendedWordParagraph)
End Interface

Interface IExtendedWordParagraph
    Inherits IWordParagraph
    Sub SomeCustomActionHere()
End Interface
```

Having this system of inheritance allows me to unit test my extended wrappers, whilst I am not too worried about the stability of the Office and Word wrappers, as they basically are a mirror of `Microsoft.Office.Interop`.

Once developing my models, I was hoping to be able to refer to `MyApp As IApplication` or `As IWordApp`, where they would implicitly mean `As IApplication(Of IFile(Of IVariable))` or `As IWordApp(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable, IWordParagraph))`. How could I achieve this?

I did try this:

```
Interface IApplication
    Inherits IApplication(Of IFile(Of IVariable))
End Interface

Interface IWordApp
    Inherits IWordApp(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable, IWordParagraph))
End Interface
```

But for casting to work properly (when passing an `IWordApp` where an `IApplication` is expected), I need to have `IWordApp(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable, IWordParagraph))` to inherit `IApplication` instead of `IApplication(Of IFile(Of IVariable))`, which results in `Me.Variables` to expose `IVariable`, not `IWordVariable`.

When in reality the cascade of generics looks more like this: `IWordApp(Of IDocument(Of IVariables(Of IVariable)), IDocuments(Of IDocument(Of IVariables(Of IVariable))))`, you then understand why I am trying to cut the code required within the models.

Comment: I think you're missing an `In` or `Out` on one of your generic type specifications, and if you do that, it will just work.  Without variance, signatures must match exactly, with variance, a child or parent type can be used in place of the specified type.

Comment: You might also want an additional generic type on `IApplication` e.g. `TVariable As IVariable` and changing `T` to be `IFile(Of TVariable)`.

Comment: Changing all type parameters from `Of T As` to `Of Out T As` did indeed resolve the compilation error. This article proved very useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: Your second comment helps to improve readability when a generic interface inherits another generic interface, but it rapidly complicates things when declaring a new object: `Property MyApplication As IApplication(Of IFile(Of IVariable), IVariable)`. Any other idea, or am I doomed to either deal with it, or give up with generics and `Overload` & `DirectCast` all the members inherited by a parent interface?

Comment: No other ideas, unfortunately; I think the only type inference for generics is on generic methods, and even then, it only works when everything can be inferred (no partial inference).

Comment: Just wanted to update you as I read about using aliases, where I can state: `Imports IWordApplication = MyNamespace.IWordApplication(Of MyNamespace.IWordDocument(Of MyNamespace.IWordVariable))`, which works like a charm! That requires adding such aliases at the top of each file where I am using the this framework, but improves readability by a lot!

Comment: I am also seeking to improve general code here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230062/cascading-interfaces-for-wrapping-vsto-microsoft-office-interop

Comment: And since we are lucky VB.Net users (because C# won't let you), `Imports` can be defined project wide, through the project Properties -> References panel. I am rather against this, but it is definitely an option.