# Type argument does not inherit from or implement the constraint type error

Tags: vb.net, generics

I am trying to create generic Sports classes using Generic types. My top-level object is a Sport that contains Teams and Players objects:

**Sports Class**

```
Public Class Sport(Of TTeams As {Teams(Of Team(Of Players(Of Player))), New}, TPlayers As {Players(Of Player), New})
    Public Teams As New TTeams
    Public Players As New TPlayers
End Class
```

`Teams` and `Players` are also generic:

**Teams and Team classes**

```
Public Class Teams(Of TTeam As {Team(Of Players(Of Player)), New})

    Protected _teams As List(Of TTeam)

    Sub New()
        _teams = New List(Of TTeam)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetByCity(city As String) As TTeam
        Dim team As TTeam = _teams.Find(Function(t As TTeam) t.City = city)

        If team Is Nothing Then
            ' Create team
            team = New TTeam
            team.City = city
            _teams.Add(team)
        End If

        Return team

    End Function

End Class

Public Class Team(Of TPlayers As Players(Of Player))
    Public Property City As String
    Protected _players As TPlayers
End Class
```

Team contains a subset of players (`_players`). The code is not complete to keep it simple.

**Players and Player classes**

```
Public Class Players(Of TPlayer As {Player, New})

    Protected _players As List(Of TPlayer)

    Sub New()
        _players = New List(Of TPlayer)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetByName(name As String) As TPlayer
        Dim player As TPlayer = _players.Find(Function(p As TPlayer) p.Name = name)

        If player Is Nothing Then
            ' Create player
            player = New TPlayer
            player.Name = name
            _players.Add(player)
        End If

        Return player

    End Function

End Class

Public Class Player
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Number As Integer
End Class
```

All of this seems good so far hopefully. Next step is where things become confusing, when I try to use these for a specific sport:

**Baseball implementation**

```
Public Class Baseball
    Inherits Sport(Of BaseballTeams, BaseballPlayers)
End Class

Public Class BaseballTeam
    Inherits Team(Of BaseballPlayers)

    Public Property League As String
    Public Property Division As String

End Class

Public Class BaseballTeams
    Inherits Teams(Of BaseballTeam)

    Public Function GetLeagueTeams(ByVal league As String) As List(Of BaseballTeam)
        Return _teams.FindAll(Function(t As BaseballTeam) t.League = league)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class BaseballPlayer
    Inherits Player

    Public Property BattingAverage As Single

End Class

Public Class BaseballPlayers
    Inherits Players(Of BaseballPlayer)

End Class
```

I get 4 errors (BC32044):

1. For `Baseball` Class:

> Type argument 'BaseballTeams' does not inherit from or implement the
>   constraint type 'Teams(Of Team(Of Players(Of Player)))'

2. For `Baseball` Class:

> Type argument 'BaseballPlayers' does not inherit from or implement the
>   constraint type 'Players(Of Player)'

3. For `BaseballTeam` Class:

> Type argument 'BaseballPlayers' does not inherit from or implement the
>   constraint type 'Players(Of Player)'.

4. For `BaseballTeams` Class:

> Type argument 'BaseballTeam' does not inherit from or implement the
>   constraint type 'Team(Of Players(Of Player))'

I can't understand what is wrong with the implementation. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for reading my question.

---

**Edit 1**: I have tried passing all types directly into the Sport class definition:

```
Public Class Sport(Of TTeams As {Teams(Of TTeam, TPlayers), New}, TTeam As Team(Of TPlayers), TPlayers As {Players(Of TPlayer), New}, TPlayer As {Player, New})
    Public Teams As New TTeams
    Public Players As New TPlayers
End Class
```

and this:

```
Public Class Teams(Of TTeam As {Team(Of TPlayers), New}, TPlayers As Players(Of TPlayer), TPlayer As Player)
```

I was hoping that I could simplify the declaration by defining the types within the declaration itself. This is not getting me any further, just giving more errors.

Comment: That is horrifying.  Nobody will ever be able to effectively maintain that spaghetti mess.  I would strongly suggest you rethink your inheritance architecture.

Comment: It is and I am trying to find a better approach. I feel the architecture of how to break down a sport into teams and players is reasonable, it just gets very ugly with Generic types which I am taking a shot at. Any help other than pointing out the obvious - it's a mess - would be appreciated.

Comment: `Inherits Sport(Of BaseballTeams, BaseballPlayers)`  But BaseballTeams is already inheriting from a Team(of BaseballPlayers).  Yes, very confusing. I would ditch the generics.  Just use an Interface to define common properties, etc. that a Baseball team and a Football team, etc. would implement.

Comment: @LarsTech even though there's not much code in the generic classes shown here, they would contain a good amount of code all sports teams and players share. With Interfaces, wouldn't I have to duplicate that same code for every sport?

Comment: You could define the interface, write a base class implementing this interface and holding all the "generic" code and make all other classes inherits this base class.

Comment: You may need some well-placed `In` or `Out` on the generic parameters.  Also see this question that was asked recently that was resolved with variance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202355/cascading-generic-interfaces

Comment: A base or abstract class would work too.  Your generics is making everything really complicated and isn't really applicable, since you want something very specific and not very generic.

Comment: @Craig thanks for the link, looks like a similar situation, will look into In/Out parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work by passing `TPlayer` and `TTeam` down the chain instead. Still a little difficult to read but it works:

**Sport**

```
Public Class Sport(Of TPlayer As {Player, New}, TTeam As {Team(Of TPlayer), New})

    Public Teams As New Teams(Of TPlayer, TTeam)
    Public Players As New Players(Of TPlayer)

End Class
```

**Teams and Team**

```
Public Class Teams(Of TPlayer As {Player, New}, TTeam As {Team(Of TPlayer), New})

    Protected _teams As List(Of TTeam)

    Sub New()
        _teams = New List(Of TTeam)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetByCity(city As String) As TTeam

        Dim team As TTeam = _teams.Find(Function(t As TTeam) t.City = city)

        If team Is Nothing Then
            ' Create team
            team = New TTeam
            team.City = city
            _teams.Add(team)
        End If

        Return team

    End Function

End Class

Public Class Team(Of TPlayer As {Player, New})

    Public Property City As String
    Public Players As New Players(Of TPlayer)

End Class
```

**Players and Player**

```
Public Class Players(Of TPlayer As {Player, New})

    Protected _players As New List(Of TPlayer)

    Sub New()
        _players = New List(Of TPlayer)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetByName(name As String) As TPlayer
        Dim player As TPlayer = _players.Find(Function(p As TPlayer) p.Name = name)

        If player Is Nothing Then
            ' Create player
            player = New TPlayer
            player.Name = name
            _players.Add(player)
        End If

        Return player

    End Function

End Class

Public Class Player

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Number As Integer

End Class
```

Finally, the Baseball implementation and test code:

**Baseball implementation**

```
Public Class Baseball
    Inherits Sport(Of BaseballPlayer, BaseballTeam)
End Class

Public Class BaseballTeams
    Inherits Teams(Of BaseballPlayer, BaseballTeam)

    Public Function GetLeagueTeams(ByVal league As String) As List(Of BaseballTeam)
        Return _teams.FindAll(Function(t As BaseballTeam) t.League = league)
    End Function

End Class
Public Class BaseballTeam
    Inherits Team(Of BaseballPlayer)

    Public Property League As String
    Public Property Division As String

End Class

Public Class BaseballPlayers
    Inherits Players(Of BaseballPlayer)

End Class

Public Class BaseballPlayer
    Inherits Player

    Public Property BattingAverage As Single

End Class
```

**Testing**

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim league As New Baseball
    Dim team As BaseballTeam
    Dim player As BaseballPlayer

    team = league.Teams.GetByCity("Los Angeles")
    player = team.Players.GetByName("Ohtani")

    player.BattingAverage = 0.286
    player.Number = 17

    MsgBox(player.Name & " #" & player.Number & " (" & team.City & "): " & player.BattingAverage)

End Sub
```

Thanks for the reading this question and answer. Even though it looks horrifying, it works and I hope this code can help others.